# Using CURL to return JSON from API in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, get

How can I `GET` the contents of this **API** using the given method of CURL?

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://api.rezdy.com/v1/products?limit=2&offset=0'
```

It should give a response of

```
{
"requestStatus": {
    "success": false,
    "error": {
      "errorCode": "4",
      "errorMessage": "Missing API Key"
    }
  }
}
```

All attempts at using render the page empty and other methods of extracting the data from the **API** such as JS have a CORS issue.

Comment: Can you show the PHP code you're attempting to use? Note that the response status for that request is `401 Unauthorised` so you'd need to ensure whatever you're using can report on non-successful requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this PHP code :

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.rezdy.com/v1/products?limit=2&offset=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Output :

```
{  
    "requestStatus":{  
        "success":false,
        "error":{  
            "errorCode":"4",
            "errorMessage":"Missing API Key"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is great. How can I output this to the page? I have in the past just used  something along `$html[]="<span>$result</span>";`

Comment: You need to convert JSON string to PHP using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), then you can use it in your page.